# Reinstalling GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

So, I bought a 1tb HHD to install Ubuntu on with plenty of room for files and games. I also dowloaded the 16.04 ISO and used RUFUS to put that on a 32gb USB stick. After that, i unplug my SSD which i have windows 10 installed on and another HHD which has my Steam games on and some other crap. I went into my BIOS and set the USB stick as my boot priority and booted into Ubuntu. I changed my "quick splash" in try ubuntu to "nomodeset"  and hit F10 (because of nvidia GPU errors) All goes well, I install Ubuntu, select the drive, and wait. "Fatal error, Failed to install boot-loader" I have 3 options, and each lead to horror.

1. select different drive
2. continue without boot-loader
3. Cancel "messing up with boot and crap", I don't remember much

I click on "Continue without Boot-loader" and hit "OK". The OK button is unresponsive. -_- welp, Seems to be a Bug (it has been for 6 years i heard)

Next move, Restart PC (worst decision of my life) I thought my windows would be safe, since i unplugged it and wasn't to worried, Right? I'm not 100% sure, but i think my Windows crap is safe. I don't care about my steam games since i can reinstall them, i just want to boot from my SSD which i have been doing. My friend said that my Grub was messed with, and i have to reinstall that. I choose Boot-Repair as my weapon, and fired it up. (still on Ubuntu OS) "Scanning systems (os-prober). This may require several minutes..." I wait 2 hours and nothing. At this point, I cant use Ubuntu (Im currently typing this on the "try Ubuntu option") and my Windows 10 is done for, or so i think. I anyone could solve this problem, allowing me to just boot into windows again, I'd be glad to donate to you on Paypal.

Thanks

Comment: please post some specifics about your pc - most importantly: how many harddrives you actually have? which were plugged in during installation? it is a bit difficult to decipher this from your story... also i think that windows installation media allows you to repair existing windows installations

Comment: For Windows if UEFI, removing a drive makes UEFI forget entries in its NVRAM. Most UEFI refind Windows ok, but not much else. Can you use f10 or f12 UEFI boot menu to boot Windows? If you disconnected drive, there is no way grub could interfere with Windows. Did you try to install Ubuntu in BIOS mode on gpt drive without bios_grub partition or in UEFI mode without ESP - efi system partition on sda?

Comment: If you had unplugged your SSD when trying to install Ubuntu on HDD then all you have to do is unplug your HDD and put your SSD back into drive bay 1, plug it in and boot your machine. Your old windows should be back and the failed Ubuntu installation will be on the unplugged HDD. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

In this case i think the best way is set windows boot menu using windows installation media and command promt  `(bootrec.exe /fixboot or bootrec.exe /fixmbr or /rebuildbcd)`,after that if windows boot loader come you can add in your boot menu ubuntu using software called `EasyBCD`.

Onother way is to reinstall `grub` package using `Synaptic Package Manager` (when you install this software on your linux machine than you have to search grub and there are some packages named `dgrub`, but i think you have mark for reinstallation package named `grub-common`.) Both of them must be work.

Comment: I have a boot mode selection in my BIOS. I can either do UEFI only of LEGACY + UEFI. Its currently set on LEGACY + UEFI

Comment: That is BIOS menu.